# CreateEventW unexpectedly fails

Tags: c++, winapi

If I write a simple code like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE  hEvent = CreateEventW( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"EVENTTEST" );
    if (hEvent==NULL){
            cout<<"Error "<<GetLastError();
    }
    else{
            cout<<"Success";
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

the code runs with success message but if I add some declaration in general scope above main (here I only add a line of code by declaring a bool variable) the function CreateEvenetW Fails with error code 998.
If I use CreateEvent instead of CreateEventW no problem will occur. But I wanna know what happens to CreateEventW when I add a simple variable declaration like this:

```
bool x=true;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE  hEvent = CreateEventW( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"EVENTTEST" );
    if (hEvent==NULL){
            cout<<"Error "<<GetLastError();
    }
    else{
            cout<<"Success";
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

These strange and unexpected errors worries me about using some winapi functions.

I should mention the code is compiled in Borland c++ 6

EDIT: If I declare the variable without initialization (like this: bool x) the error doesn't happen. Also this problem occurs only with some data types.I checked types (int,double) and program ran with "Success" message. But types (char,bool) causes error when they are initialized.

Comment: The return values are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) but 998 is not among them (998 is ERROR_NOACCESS). Although having the functions behave differently just because of `bool x = true` sounds more like a problem with a compiler from 2002 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder

Comment: @herohuyongtao I'm *dying* to know what that has to do with a direct-call to the Unicode version of `CreateEvent` with a hard-Unicode name. Do tell plz.

Comment: GetLastError returns 998 and from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388(v=vs.85).aspx you can see it says: Invalid access to memory location.

Comment: @WhozCraig My bad, misunderstood the question.

Comment: Please note that CreateEvent last parameter is Char * not wchat_t and I'll pass "EVENTTEST" instead of L"EVENTTEST".

Comment: You should get the value of `GetLastError()` into a local variable and then output that: `DWORD e = GetLastError(); cout << "Error " << e << endl;`. If you do not do that, there may be code run before the call to `GetLastError()` that overwrites your actual error code.

Comment: @rodrigo I tried it. But Same result as I expected. The error code is 998. Nothing overwrites it before call to my GetLastError()

Comment: @user2808671 - did you get awaywhere with this?  I wanted to ask what happens when you run your compiled code on another (clean) machine?

Comment: @selbie Same thing happens in different computer.

Comment: @user2808671 - sorry to see you are having trouble. There's nothing about the code snippit that you have supplied that I know of that could cause CreateEvent to fail like that. My suspicion is with the Borland tools, but I can't be for sure. Visual C++ and Visual Studio have free downloads.

Comment: I tested in VS2012 and the function ran properly with success message. But I was curious why this happens in borland. I think Borand in this case can't handle memory allocation or something like this. But because of specific issues I must use borland in some cases instead of VS and I love this compiler specially for making stand alone exe. And fortunately I solved this problem just by using CreateEvent instead of CreateEventW. It was just curiosity the reason I asked this question. Thank everybody who answered

Answer (score 2):

Getting error 998 in a Windows program indicates a *very* severe problem.  You'll get this when the kernel itself can tell that the process heap is corrupted.  It is most typically generated, instead of the normal access violation you'd get for heap corruption, when the program is not in a state where it cannot safely generate the AV exception.  This happens first and foremost when the Windows loader is busy loading a DLL and runs the DllMain() entrypoint.  Some odds that your debugger shows a first-chance exception notification.  Hopefully anyway.

You'll of course never get a repro for this error with the code you posted, the problem is caused by other code.  Either inside a DLL (most likely) or in the initialization code that runs before your main() function is entered.  Corrupting the heap is of course a standard C++ problem.  You are likely to find help from the [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) tool.  Good luck with it.

Comment: As I said this SIMPLE code ALONE runs and fails. Of course it's a small part of a bigger project but THIS code has the problem I talked about. What is before this code is just some include definitions and nothing more.

Comment: Avoid yelling.  I never said that it was your code that had the problem.  There's never any lack of shovelware injecting DLLs into processes.  I gave you a very specific troubleshooting recommendation, what did AppVerifier tell you?

Comment: I didn't yell buddy. The AppVerifier log reports No Error and No Warning

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is a shot in the dark guess.

Since you are creating a named event ("EVENTTEST"), some other process (possibly still running) may have previously created the event with a different set of permissions. Maybe one instance ran in a command shell with admin privs and the failed instance did not?

In other words, this is some sort of security/ACL issue with named kernel handles.

Another guess: The "x=true" line is just red herring and the problem is somewhat timing dependent.

You could check the Event logs (Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Event Viewer). Then check the Application, System, and Security logs under the "Windows Logs" folder. It might reveal something...

Otherwise, reboot and try again.  And unless you need to the Event handle to work across different processes, just replace "EVENTTEST" with NULL and let the threads within the same process just share the handle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I checked this code many times in two different computers with same result. whenever I remove that line the function succeeds when again adding that line it fails... According to what you mentioned I Set the last parameter to NULL and the error went away. But I need the event to have a name.Because if another instance of program runs then by checking this event it must close. I don't want more than one instance for my program being executed. Anyway I will check system logs too.

Comment: I took a look at windows logs but not found anything relating to issue